# IE9 form= attribute not working

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer-9

I have multiple forms on a complex page with fields separated by considerable intervening HTML. In firefox and chrome, I can declare a form and close it, then put a form="xxx" attribute in the fields to be associated with the form. This does not appear to work in IE9.

Here is a simplified example:

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST["field1"])) echo "Field1: " . $_POST["field1"] . "<br>";
if (isset($_POST["Btn1"])) echo "Btn1: " . $_POST["Btn1"] . "<br>";
if (isset($_POST["Btn2"])) echo "Btn2: " . $_POST["Btn2"] . "<br>";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" media="all">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv-printshiv.js" media="all"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" action="Test.php" method="POST"></form>
    <input type="text" form="form1" id="field1" name="field1" value="text input">
    <button type="submit" form="form1" id="Btn1" name="Btn1" value="Btn1" title="Btn1">
      Btn1</button>
    <input type="submit" form="form1" id="Btn2" name="Btn2" value="Btn2" title="Btn2">
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried adding
    < meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
... no change.

... anybody else run across this "feature" and how do I fix it?

Comment: so what exactly is the error that you get? ie, all form elements submit to 1 form?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There is no closing FORM tag.

Comment: No, I get nothing -- like the POST never occurred!

Comment: Yes - there IS a closing form tag (at the end of the opening form tag. This style is accepted in HTML5 by all other browsers. Note that the field and buttons have a form="form1" attribute.

Comment: Seriously? If you have two forms on one page, how would the form know which elements are in FORM-A and not in FORM-B?

Comment: Please notice that each element has a form="form1" attribute. If there are multiple forms, as long as each has its own id, the form="xxx" attribute associates that element with a particular form. This is working just fine on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: have you specified doctype ?

Answer (score 3):

There does not seem to be any information about support to the `form` attribute in [Microsoft’s info on support to HTML5 forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). A quick test suggests that even IE 10 does not support it.

So consider simplifying the structure. Intervening HTML should not be a problem, as long as your are not trying to overlap or nest forms.

Comment: nearly everytime i go to answer something, and i see that jukka has answered, i am happy. full of good responses, you are.

Comment: You are correct, there is no mention of supporting the form attribute from Microsoft. There is however mention of it in the HTML5 spec (section 4.10.18) from W3C. I am already in the process of re-vamping all of my code (some 40+ pages) to avoid the situation.

Answer (score 0):

The `form` attribute is an HTML5 addition. It won't work in browsers too old to support HTML5.

Comment: So, you're telling me that IE9 (which is the latest version you can run on Vista) is too old to support HTML5. I guess IE isn't anywhere near the claims they make about being HTML5 compatible.

Comment: @user2093616: Yes. Although this support overview doesn't mention the `form` attribute, you can see that you need IE 10 for almost all HTML5 forms features: http://www.wufoo.com/html5/

Answer (score -1):

You need to close the form tag after the fields, it should look like this:

```
<form id="form1" action="Test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" form="form1" id="field1" name="field1" value="text input">
    <button type="submit" form="form1" id="Btn1" name="Btn1" value="Btn1" title="Btn1">
      Btn1</button>
    <input type="submit" form="form1" id="Btn2" name="Btn2" value="Btn2" title="Btn2">
</form>
```

Add also labels to each field to make the form accessible.